# PHP regex strip comma and space from beginning and end of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have some strings like this

```
", One "
", One , Two"
"One, Two "
" One,Two, "
" ,Two ,Three "
```

**EDIT 2:** Some strings have two words between coma like `", Two ,Three, Twenty Five, Six"`.

and need to remove **space and or comma** at the beginning and end of the string only tried few regex with **preg_replace()**, but they replace all occurrences.

**EDIT:** Actually would be great to remove all clutter like `!@#$%^&*(` etc whatever is at the end and beginning of string, but not in between.

Optionally need to make strings look proper by placing **word** then **comma** then **space** then **another word** (if there's comma one in between words).

Example `"One,Two  ,Three , Four"` into `"One, Two, Three, Four"`.

P.S. Please provide answer as two separate regex as its easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the regex `\b\w+\b` to extract words and then reformat like this:

```
<?php

$strings = [", One ",
    ", One , Two",
    "One, Two ",
    " One,Two, ",
    " ,Two ,Three ",
    ", Two ,Three, Twenty Five, Six"];
foreach($strings as &$str)
{
    preg_match_all('/\b[\w\s]+\b/',$str,$matches);
    $neat = '';
    foreach($matches[0] as $word)
    {
        $neat .= $word.', ';
    }
    $neat = rtrim($neat,', ');
    $str = $neat;
}
print_r($strings);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => One
    [1] => One, Two
    [2] => One, Two
    [3] => One, Two
    [4] => Two, Three
    [5] => Two, Three, Twenty Five, Six
)
```

Comment: OP said he had multiple strings, not a single string containing all those, so I made an array

Comment: Nice approach, but it does not not work if there's two words in string 

e.g.  `,  Two ,Three, Twenty Five, Six ` it returns , `Two, Three, Twenty, Five, Six`

Comment: @RomanToasov , It's returning what exactly OP asked, what's wrong with it, if so what should have been correct ouput ? :)

Comment: Correct would be `Two, Three, Twenty Five, Six `  note  `Twenty Five `  without coma. I did not think i need to put that in example string as i was just asking how to edit beginning and end parts of string.

Comment: @RomanToasov , please add it in question , I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to mutate the input strings into consistent comma+space delimited strings, there is no reason to form temporary arrays -- especially if you are open to a regular expression technique.

1. trim all spaces and commas from the front and back of the input string, then
2. replace one-or-more comma or space characters with your standardized comma+space glue.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iQXW1))

```
$tests = [
    ", One ,,  ,,",
    ", Two , Three",
    "Four, Five ",
    " Six,Seven, ",
    " ,Eight ,Nine , , , , Ten ,",
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    var_export(
        preg_replace('/[, ]+/', ', ', trim($test, ', '))
    );
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'One'
'Two, Three'
'Four, Five'
'Six, Seven'
'Eight, Nine, Ten'
```

---

If you **require** at least one comma as a delimiting sequence in your input strings, then this adjusted regex will do: `/[, ]*,[, ]*/`. Demo: https://3v4l.org/HeCFp  This will preserve spaces within a value.

`",,Eleventy Twelve , , Thrirteen    "` -> `"Eleventy Twelve, Thrirteen"`

---

If you want to remove "junk characters" at the start and end of your input string, just add the `!@#$%^&*(` characters to the "character mask" parameter of `trim()` --> `, !@#$%^&*(`.